# Visibility of ES6 class created via an eval statement

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eval, visibility

As I go through the process of looking at techniques to improve the load speed & performance of my hybrid Cordova/Android app one of the things I am doing is making the original DOM tree that has to be constructed as simple as possible and then loading "page templates" as and when required.  This technique works - very well with speed improvements that are quite remarkable.  However, to do this I make extensive use of `eval` and this has led me to find something quite strange.  Consider the following code

```
eval("class TestAlone{static sayHello(){alert('Hello Alone');}}"); 
TestAlone.sayHello();
```

> VM362:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: TestAlone is not defined

Now consider the following code

```
eval("window.TesttOnWindow = class TestOnWindow{static sayHello(){alert('Hello from window');}}"); 
TestOnWindow.sayHello();
```

> Produces the alert as expected.

This can easily be tested directly in the Chrome debugger console.

I have to admit to not fully understanding the underlying reasons here.  However, the message in the debugger console makes me think that in the first instance the `TestAlone` class declaration is vanishing into a (safe? sandboxed?) VM so it can no longer be accessed from my "normal" code.  In the second instance the class declaration is being attached to the global `window` object and thus remains visible.

Is this even anywhere near to being the right explanation.  I'd much appreciate if anyone who understands such matters more than I could weigh in and comment.

Comment: Not a VM, just a separate environment. From the spec, as a note: *"

The eval code cannot instantiate variable or function bindings in the variable environment of the calling context that invoked the eval if the calling context is evaluating formal parameter initializers or if either the code of the calling context or the eval code is strict mode code. Instead such bindings are instantiated in a new VariableEnvironment that is only accessible to the eval code. Bindings introduced by `let`, `const`, or `class` declarations are always instantiated in a new LexicalEnvironment."*

Comment: ^ The last sentence is especially relevant. https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-performeval

Comment: My gut is `class` declaration acts similar to `let` and `const` in eval. With let and const eval will create new lexical environment so those variables won't be available outside eval.

Comment: What happens to the `VariableEnvironment` once the `eval` code has finished executing?  It is silently garbage collected?

Comment: Probably depends on the rest of the code that is `eval`ed. If it contains a closure that is referenceable from the outside, it will live on.

Comment: Thanks.  Turn your comments into an answer so I can accept + upvote.